# How to adjust size of parent element when child elements overflow, but keep size when it doesn't?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I have been cracking my head over this. Let's say I want a `div` to have background color and cover the whole page so I set it's height to 100vh. if I add fixed sized elements inside at first it'd be fine but eventually it'll start to overflow the parent container.

Here's some example code bellow:

```
<!-- index.html -->
  <div class="parent-box">
    <div class="child-box"> Child box</div>
    <div class="child-box"> Child box</div>
    <div class="child-box"> Child box</div>
    <div class="child-box"> Child box</div>
    <div class="child-box"> Child box</div>
  </div>
```

```
// style.css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-box {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
.child-box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Result:
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDT7u.png)

Basically, I'm asking **how to keep the default size of my parent element the same, while allowing it to grow bigger if it overflows.**

Comment: replace height by min-height ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be   **min-height: 100vh** Instead of height: 100vh